# How to produce a memory image in Visual Studio

Tags: image, memory, intellitrace, code-map

In Visual Studio, is there a way to produce a memory image of a solution? Similar to the Show on Code Map, except the image would keep track of pointers, values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try debugger map, it's a CodeMap that also maps your stack trace. Once you're debugging and you've hit a breakpoint, go to:

> Debug > Show Call Stack on Code Map

Other than this, there is no "in the box" tool that allows you build a visual map of your program at run time.